# How to insert Route to the top of RouteCollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am need to insert a route during the mvc application processing. I am in stuck because i can use MapPageRoute only to add new route to the end of routings table, and i can use Insert to add route to the start of collection, but in this case i can't define this routing name, so i can't manage it in future.

So the question: is any opportunity to add route with defined name to the start of routes table exists?

Does anyone know?

p.s. map to the end and use Reverse is bad idea.

Comment: Can you give an example as to why you won't know the routes ahead of time?

Comment: Administrator of site should have opportunity to add new aliases for some pages. The most clear solution is the using of routes

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of Map and insert. Mapping a route returns a Route object. You can map a route, immediately remove it and then Insert it like so:

```
Route r = routes.MapRoute(
                                "SomeName", // Route name
                                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                            );
routes.Remove(r);
routes.Insert(0, r);
```

This gets you a named route at the top of your Route Table.

Comment: walk to try it... ...it is'nt works, name isn't a property of a route, it is the key, that removes with the removed route.